# Problem Bootstrap 4 btn-group-toggle conflict with textbox inside

Tags: bootstrap-4, listjs

I have problem with bootstrap when I try add dropdown with textbox and I try to find something:

```html
<script async src="//jsfiddle.net/socheth/52o13tgd/1/embed/"></script>
```

A
        
        
             B
            
        
             C
            
        
             D
        

        
            

            
                OTHERS

E

F

G

H

I

Comment: explain in breif